# Why would a .NET console app delete itself?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, access-denied

I opened Visual Studio, created a console app, added a couple lines to test a Uri method and clicked the Play (Debug) button.  Got an access denied error.

So I went into the output directory, and I could see the executable appearing when I build the project.  However, when I double click it in explorer to run it, it deletes itself!

That explains the access denied error when trying to debug it, because the app deletes itself immediately upon running. If I copy it out of the directory onto my desktop and run it, it also deletes itself there.

Why would Visual Studio create a file that behaves this way?  What is causing the file to delete itself when executed?

Here is the whole app. If I remove all lines but Console.ReadLine, it's fine. But this configuration, and even with other URLs, the app deletes itself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("https://facebook.com/");
            var s = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            int i = 0;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write some code that deletes files by any chance?

Comment: No I think that you have something in your code that does that. By the way, explaining a problem without the relevant code is not easy to figure out the problem

Comment: No, but it is the code causing it. No idea why though. Certainly not the behavior intended. I'll post it.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone else is able to reproduce this.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this.  Could there be a bug in Uri or Uri.GetLeftPart that causes an executable to delete itself? I'm running the latest, most up-to-date version of visual studio, targeting .NET 4.6.1.  This is just a simple console app.

Comment: Just tried. No way. The app is there and doesn't disappear. Did you check if you have some build scripts running?

Comment: No build scripts.  This is happening to other people here in my office as well, although they didn't notice the file deleting itself.   It's strange that altering the code by removing the first two or 3 lines stops the issue from happening, and adding them back causes it to start again.

Comment: It's strictly the first line that's causing it: var uri = new Uri("https://facebook.com/"). With that line present, the file deletes itself. No other lines have this effect.

Comment: I'd suspect an overzealous virus scanner... Or corporate executable whitelist scheme....

Comment: I'd second the virus scanner theory. It sounds like a heuristic virus scanner getting upset by the URL access. Check your virus scanner quarantine queue.

Comment: Yep. That was it!  I uploaded it to VirusTotal.  Tested clean for everything, EXCEPT CloudStrikeFalcon, which I know I'm running on this machine. It's obviously a false-positive.  Nice to know it just deletes a file without any warning or indication whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Virus scanner was silently deleting the file. It's obviously a false-positive, as this is just a basic console app. Someone suggested it might be a heuristic virus scanner, and sure enough, when I scanned the file on VirusTotal, the virus scanner I know for a fact is installed on this machine thinks the file is a problem.

[image]